# Delphi + Firebird + ZEOS - Update on real-time data

Tags: delphi, refresh, firebird, zeos

Necessary that the two systems networked, open on different computers, update the information among themselves semque I need to close and re-open the executable. I'm using Firebird + ZEOS and even if I refresh the tables one does not see the update in real time on the other. Need to do something in ZConnection for this to work?

Comment: You just probably need to start a new transaction on the reading side. However, I have almost no experience with Zeos to tell you more details. Is there some sort of autocommit property on your connection object ? If so, what is its value ?

Comment: I would need to see your code (and know your `Zeos` version), but I guess that you either set `Autocommit` to false, or you started an `explicit transaction` and are not commiting it.